# Unload library failed on linux with poco

Tags: c++, linux, poco-libraries

I'm using poco for loading and unloading libraries. Everything is working fine on windws, but on Linux it is failing on `poco::ClassLoader::unloadLibrary(libraryName)` function call. It just gets in this function and it never comes out and it does not throw exception. I have one more `.so` library and it is working just fine.

I know you cannot tell me exact reason why is it failling, but it could help me if I knew what are possible reasons for this, and maybe is there some tool that could help me to figure it out?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried getting the sources and attaching a debugger so you can see the exact spot where it blocks?

Comment: I do not have debbuger for Linux currently, I'll have to find something, it seems there is no other way to figure this out :S

Comment: shouldnt gdb be installed on most linus distribution automatically? If its not on your system try `sudo apt-get install gdb`

Answer (score 0):

It may be waiting for some resources to get released and freed. Is there any chance which poco tracks down objects created ?! It may be because of a lock or state which the unload method is waiting for to happen to get unlocked. You can use a memory profiler to check those objects which they are not released.

Comment: Here is what I have managed to find out: 
 1. Before unloading shared library I used sleep(60) so I can check which shared libraries are loaded in my process
 2. I managed to catch some exception from poco function unloadLibrary, so in catch block I placed infinite loop.
 4. Started my program, and before poco::unloadLibrary is called I had a time to check if there is my shared library loaded with lsof -p <PID>, and it was there
 5. After one minute, I checked it once again, and it was not there anymore

So, it is unloaded, although poco throwed exception ...
I'll check what is exception

Comment: It is throwing Poco::SystemException but I cannot see the message. When I try to print it with my debugs system it crashes, and the same thing happens if I try to print message in terminal.
If I just catch exception and do nothing, I have no problems, and library is unloaded, but I do not like catching exception and ignore it ...